# get the value of an <div> tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am interested in when choosing an option from a drop-down list the value of the selected option that stá visualiando in a < div > that value is captured in a javascript variable. The list referred to originated in an AJAX routine that queries a database. On page php , where there is a div shown above . I need your help to take this value from the list.

Comment: divs don't have values. values are for form/input fields. divs have CONTENT. `content = document.getElementById('id_of_div').innerHTML;`

Comment: ^ unless you're actually manipulating HTML, use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: Hard to understand your english.... do you mean that when someone selects an option from your dropdown, you take that id, do an ajax call to get content for their selection, and then put that returned content into a div on the page?  That's how your description reads to me, but your subject seems different.  Post code = universal language

Comment: `textContent` only support IE 9+, `innerHTML` supports old browser too

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you meant for your question read the way RightClick explained it in the comments, you need something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
var ids = $('.dropdown').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();//Get array of ids


    var options = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var anchor = options[i];
        anchor.onclick = function() {
            var h = new XMLHttpRequest();
            h.open("GET", "/myDB?q="+ids[i], true);//This should be synchronous
            h.send();
            document.getElementById("responseDiv").innerHTML = h.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

`